# Resistor Identification

Tags: resistors, identification

Need help to identify resistor found in car ECU. Colour: Solid sky blue. Markings are: 100J and .36.  Need explanation of what markings refer to.
 See example pic:

[image: Burned resistor]

([Source](http://s564.photobucket.com/user/vincez32/media/leakingresistor2_zps6cd19275.jpg.html))

Comment: what is the measured resistor value? and the size of the resistor

Comment: (a) The markings seem to include ".36" not ".30" as you mentioned. Please clarify. (b) Just a thought - if that isn't flux that we're seeing, but if the PCB has in fact been burned, then there will be a cause for that elsewhere. Meaning that unless you find & fix that underlying cause first, a replacement component will likely be affected in a similar way.

Comment: Hi, resister is 10 ohm (found another on the circuit board and tested). The length is 9mm and diameter is 3mm. Yes mine is .30 (just example pic)

Comment: If you replace the resistor it may blow again .There may be other damage .

Answer (score 1):

This may be using the lettering system for resistors: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/resistors-value-letter-digit-code-d_1656.html

However, I also found a resistor with 100J in the part number that happened to be 10 ohms? http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/IRC-TT-Electronics/MHP20-100J/?qs=wRBQ8ZgBZ99bTLS2IzzmFw%3D%3D

The only way to be sure is to borrow a multimeter!